# Angular.js memory leak with ngRepeat on polled data

Tags: memory-leaks, angularjs

I've got what seems to be a memory leak in my angular.js app.  Basically, the page consists of a table of information that is updated every five seconds from the JSON-encoded result of an AJAX call.  I've created a simplified jsfiddle version here: http://jsfiddle.net/alalonde/TtGXW/6/

The controller:

```
function HostController($scope, $timeout, Data) {
  $scope.encoders = Data.load();
  $scope.refreshInterval = 5;

  $scope.reload = function () {
    $scope.encoders = Data.load();
  };

  $timeout(function doReload() {
    $scope.reload();
    $timeout(doReload, $scope.refreshInterval * 1000);
  }, 5000);
}
```

A snippet of the template:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" ng-controller="HostController">
  <tr>
    <th>Status</th>
  <th>...
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="enc in encoders">
    <td>
      <div>{{ enc.name }}</div>
      <div ng-show="enc.version">
        v{{ enc.version.major }}.{{ enc.version.minor }}-{{ enc.version.rev }}
        <span ng-show="enc.version.user">- {{ enc.version.user }}</span>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

When taking a heap snapshot in Chrome every minute or so, the memory usage rises slightly each time.  I've applied Igor Minar's fix to my local angular.js (https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/bd524fc4e5fc0feffe85632a7a6560da6bd9b762) which helped a lot, but the memory usage is still inexorably creeping up.

Any hints on using the Chrome memory profiler with angular.js would be appreciated.

Comment: I can't reproduce the mem leak in jsfiddle. I left the app running for a while and all I see is the usual GC pattern with memory being released once enough of garbage has accumulated.

Does the jsfiddle actually leak on your machine? Can you provide browser version info?

Comment: Also please file a bug at https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues if the issue is indeed reproducible.

Comment: Here is a [screenshot of my chrome memory profiler](http://files.boxelderweb.com/angular-chrome-memory-profiler.png).  I changed the refreshInterval to 1 second to expedite things.  There is a 0.47MB increase over 15 minutes or so.  Expanding the (array) listing, it seems all the HTML elements beneath and including the <tr> are leaking.  @IgorMinar can you verify?  If so I will file a bug.

Comment: nope. I can't repro. I changed the timeout to 1ms and let it run overnight on chrome canary (27.0.1415.0) and stable (24.0.1312.57) and I still don't see any mem increase. this is the fiddle I tested: http://jsfiddle.net/TtGXW/9/show/

Comment: if you can change the example somehow to make it leak please open a bug report. I'm not good at following SO updates.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue with memory consumption when I was polling for data and using ng-repeat to loop over it and render the rows.

When I used "item in items" I got ever increasing memory usage but when I used "item in items track by $index" the memory usage was stable and the GC cleaned up properly.

Comment: I was having a memory leak issue and this fixed it for me (using angular v1.1.5) so thanks!  Were you able to find out any further information as to why this fixes the memory leak?

Comment: Had the same issue in AngularJs 1.6.4 "track by $index" fixed the memory leak, but i cannot use "track by $index | filter: myfilter" (e.g. a filter) so I set a timer so the page refreshes every 30 minutes.